# Unable to activate Dart Devtools

Tags: flutter, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLhok.png)On opening dart devtools in VS its showing Dart devtools exited with code 255 . 
I even tried to activating it from terminal in VS by typing *flutter pub global activate devtools* but its showing could not find a command named “global” for “flutter pub”
[error shown on terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLhok.png) 
[error again shown after activating devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWTgU.png)

Comment: Could you share the full error?

Comment: yes please check I have just edited the question by uploading a screenshot of error

Answer (score 14):

Instead of using *`flutter pub global activate devtools` ,*

**Use this :**
`pub global activate devtools`

It's the correct way to **activate devtools** (if you have `pub` in your path)

> **Info** : You could use *`flutter pub global activate devtools`* ,if you have `flutter` in your path .

Comment: what worked for me was flutter pub global activate devtools

Answer (score 6):

You have two solutions:

- Update your flutter version
- write `flutter pub pub global activate my_package` (yes, `pub` is written twice)

Comment: PS C:\Users\Dhanshree\flutter\flutter_first_app> flutter pub pub global activate my_package
Resolving dependencies...
Because pub global activate depends on my_package any which doesn't exist (could not find package my_package at https://pub.dartlang.org), version solving failed.   
pub finished with exit code 69                                                                                                                                                  ...This error is prompted now

Comment: You are supposed to replace `my_package` with whatever package you want to activate (so devtools)

Comment: Yes it worked properply. Terminal is also showing activated devtools but I'm not able to open it again its showing error dart Devtools exited with code 255. i have attached image in the question

Comment: even i fixed the warning given on terminal but again showing the same

Comment: Do what the error says, that is adding the said folder to your path

Answer (score 1):

Try to **disable your antivirus** for like 5 minutes and then go to the flutter directory

**C:\src\flutter**

and run the command

> *flutter pub global activate devtools*

**Note:** The flutter path should be set in env variables before running this.

Answer (score 1):

To activate devtools, use this command

```
dart pub global activate devtools
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried the above-mentioned solutions, however, none of them seemed to work for me:

```
flutter pub global activate devtools
The current Dart SDK version is 3.2.3.

Because pub global activate depends on devtools any which does not support null safety, version solving failed.

The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.1.0-dev <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety.
For details, see https://dart.dev/null-safety
```

I ended up executing `dart devtools` which opened up the Dev Tools.

For more information: https://docs.flutter.dev/tools/devtools/cli

Comment: The only solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + Shift + P -run command palette. Then run:
Run Flutter Upgrade

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this same issue, and also getting error messages when viewing extension pages

> Error loading webview: Error: Could not register service workers: TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker

The solution that fixed both (the error 255 Dart DevTools, and this webview error) was [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69704193/2686738) (kill all instances of VS Code, then clear VS Code caches).

Answer (score 0):

I am a mac user so you can use this command to enable dart.

```
export PATH="/Users/<MAC_USER_NAME>/Desktop/developer/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk:$PATH"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If this response is shows, then by writing in terminal --> dart devtools/flutter devtools will helps.

```
    flutter pub global activate devtools
The current Dart SDK version is 3.2.3.

Because pub global activate depends on devtools any which does not support null safety, version solving failed.

The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.1.0-dev <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety.
For details, see https://dart.dev/null-safety
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that some of the answers here are outdated:

> DevTools is shipped as part of the Dart and Flutter SDKs and is no
> longer shipped on pub. So when you upgrade Flutter, you automatically
> get the version of DevTools that is shipped with that SDK.

This means, pub commands for DevTools are depreciated, and you should **not** use legacy commands such as the following:

```
> flutter pub global activate devtools  
> dart pub global activatedevtools
```

For me trying them led to various errors. For more information see here:
https://github.com/flutter/devtools/issues/7135

Ps: As I do not have enough reputation to comment, I add my learnings as an answer here, hoping that you will avoid this pitfalls.