# Error loading webview: Error: Could not register service workers: TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I update my VSCode to v1.56.2 and open webview, I get these messages:

> Error loading webview: Error: Could not register service workers:
> TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope
> ('vscode-webview://867f875b-c5a3-4504-8de2-2e8614bdc0f8/') with script
> ('vscode-webview://867f875b-c5a3-4504-8de2-2e8614bdc0f8/service-worker.js?platform=electron&id=867f875b-c5a3-4504-8de2-2e8614bdc0f8&vscode-resource-origin=https%3A%2F%2F867f875b-c5a3-4504-8de2-2e8614bdc0f8.vscode-webview-test.com'):
> ServiceWorker cannot be started.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Surprisingly, I restarted vs code and nothing happened. Then, I restarted windows completely and the error was solved.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is a [known bug in VS Code 1.56](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/122951). It happens for some Windows users when running VS Code as an administrator

As a workaround, you can try launching VS Code with the `--no-sandbox` command line flag:

```sh
$ code --no-sandbox
```

Comment: --no-sandbox option is no longer there!? Any ideas what it changed to?

Comment: I found this solution on github issues, but it does not work if another instance still open. Closing the instances as said @Shreyash Pandey and also others was enough. The --no-sandbox was not really needed

Answer (score 489):

If you are using Ubuntu, there is probably another (maybe hidden) vscode process, which is causing the problem.

Close the vs code first and in terminal try: `killall code`.

Comment: For me, I just had to close all the vs code windows.

Comment: Nice this fixed it for me, on Ubuntu

Comment: Thanks, I'm using ubuntu 20.0.4 LTS, and this fixed my issue.

Comment: I just restarted VSCodium and it fixed it on Kubuntu.

Comment: Thanks @yavorbel -  killing all code processes worked for me, but the `killall code` did not run on my Mac (running Mojave).  Used this command to kill all code-related processes without having to reboot:  `ps -ef | grep code | awk {'print $2'} | xargs kill -9`

Comment: you could alternatively use `pkill -f vscode`

Comment: weird, flex, but ok

Comment: Thank you, Codeium (https://codeium.com/) was having the same error message and restarting vscode fixed the issue.

Comment: Don't forget to reboot if u r using fedora

Comment: This fixed it for me on Ubuntu as well! thanks @yavorbel

Comment: restarting vscode a few times worked for me. Pretty hit or miss though.

Answer (score 262):

In Windows, you can simply fix this error by clearing the cache for VSCode. Please follow the steps below:

1. Close VSCode and also kill any background processes running in the task manager. [image: Task Manager screenshot]
2. Go to the file explorer and to the path `C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Roaming\Code` and clear the contents of the folders `Cache, CachedData, CachedExtensions, CachedExtensionVSIXs (if this folder exists) and Code Cache`.
3. Open VSCode and you are good to go.

Comment: also worked on MacOS. The folders are in  `~/Library/Application Support/Code/`

Comment: Worked perfectly on Windows 11, thank you.

Comment: Worked fine for me. (I didn't need to clear `CachedConfigurations`.)
But I had to restart VS Code *twice* to make it function normally again.

Comment: Thank you @Henke , for the changes but I'd like to be more precise with the folder path as there are many newbie coders who don't know the exact path, so for them it can be confusing. I have rolled back the changes you made. Appreciate your efforts in improving the answer.

Comment: Your suggestion worked, thanks: taskkill /f /im code.exe

Comment: worked on linux. folders in ~/.config/Code

Comment: Also worked just turning VScode off and back on :)

Comment: This action helps on Windows 11 - thanks.

Comment: Thanks - This works for me also, `Windows 10 pro`, `WSL2`, `Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS`

Comment: sometimes just ending up the process is enough (step 1), so check before doing the other steps

Comment: Excellent. I also cleared CachedProfilesData and CachedConfigurations, for good measure, and did not notice and adverse effects.

Comment: This still worked 2 years later in version 1.84.2

Comment: Wonder solutions for me. Windows 10 worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 112):

I encountered this issue and am *not a Windows user*, so this is my resolution:

I found that there was an instance of VS Code open that was erroneously not shown on my dock.  I closed this instance and opened a new instance. The problem was gone.

I think the issue happened because I had a VS Code instance open, allowed a software update to run in the background, postponed the restart, opened a new and updated VS Code instance, and the old instance remained open causing conflicts.

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: Fast soluton: Open the terminal and type `killall code`.
Easy & lazy solution: Reboot your computer.

Comment: @Sydney Y can you elaborate on how you found which process did not have a instance on your dock?

Comment: @Amfasis I minimized all my open apps one by one. I think you could also Alt+Tab or use the Windows key.

Comment: I had issue opening NuGet manager. In terminal type "xkill" and click on VSCode. Issue fixed. No system restart required.

Answer (score 66):

**@tritemio** on GitHub has a great answer:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/125993#issuecomment-912439561

in short, delete cache folder:

```
# close vscode instances (make sure no process is running)

# Linux
rm -rf ~/.config/Code/Cache

# macOS
rm -rf ~/Library/Application Support/Code/Cache

# Windows PowerShell
Get-ChildItem "$env:APPDATA\code" -Directory -Filter Cache -Recurse | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse

# Windows Command Prompt (cmd.exe)
rd /s /q "%APPDATA%\Code\Cache"
```

This worked for me. But in the github thread suggestion is to delete all `*Cache*` so if previous don't work, maybe try this:

```
# close vscode instances (make sure no process is running)

# Linux
rm -rf ~/.config/Code/*Cache*

# macOS
rm -rf ~/Library/Application Support/Code/*Cache*

# Windows PowerShell
Get-ChildItem "$env:APPDATA\code" -Directory -Filter *cache* -Recurse | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse

# Windows Command Prompt (cmd.exe)
pushd "%APPDATA%\Code"
for /d /r %d in (*cache*) do rd /s /q "%d"
popd
```

Comment: This was just the ticket, with one more step: delete the folder then, if VSCode is open, restart it.

Comment: Fantastic, this worked for me. I figured I had a bad version of  VSCode and would have to reinstall it or wait for an update. Seems this isn't a new problem and isn't a mass occurrence from an update either. Mine just seemed to happen after an update. I thought an extension was broken until I realized many views were broken.

Comment: This also worked for me - fedora 37, gnome and i wasn't able to open photos, nor use markdown preview, there was maybe some update in previous days and it stopped working.. After deleting Cache everything is back to normal. Big thanks.

Answer (score 12):

On *nix systems, first close VS Code app then run `pgrep -f '/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app' | xargs kill` to clean up vscode's processes. Reopen vscode and the issue will be gone.

If on macOS, you can run the above command verbatim. If you're not on macOS or installed vscode on a different location, you need to change the argument passed to `pgrep`. You can run `ps auxww | command grep -i --color code` to find the path of vscode's running processes.

Comment: Much better solution than nuking your entire vscode cache.

Comment: WOW!!  WORKED!!  Thanks!!  ... I was installing the SVG Preview plugins and none of them worked.

Comment: On Linux this failed with: pgrep -f '/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app' | xargs kill
kill: not enough arguments

Comment: @JasonIvey That's because pgrep cannot find any matching process. Please see the 2nd paragraph, thanks!

Answer (score 11):

@tritemio, thanks for sharing.

This also seemed to solve my issues on Windows for "Extensions - Details View", "VS Code Release Notes View", "Gitlab integrated Interactive Rebase Editor", etc.

I followed your suggestion and deleted the following folders;

- %appdata%\Code - Insiders\Cache
- %appdata%\Code - Insiders\Code Cache

Answer (score 8):

The simplest solution for this problem in any version of Linux is simply to close other instances of VS code and use only one instance of VS code.
OS: Linux 20.04.3 LTS

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 7):

Happened to me when started code in windows cmd. Closed vs code and opened it from my taskbar shortcut instead, and the error was gone

Answer (score 6):

I've also encountered the same "Error loading web view" Error.
I've solved this issue by moving "vscode.app" into "Application folder" instead of "Download folder" on **macOS**.

I'll describe my "symptom" here.

1. OS: macOS 12.0.1
2. Installed 2 versions of vscode somehow, 1 under "Application folder", another under "download folder"
3. Run both vscode at the same time, the "download folder" version has no error display plugin pages, the "Application folder" version has the "Error loading webview" error
4. Checked and see 2 vscode instances running in the background

What I tried to solve this issue:

1. Tried to kill "download folder" instance, and the error remains for "application folder" instance
2. **Moved "download folder" to "application folder" and both vscode works correctly on plugin page!**

What I suspect on what the problem is?

Maybe these 2 vscode are sharing the same resource(could be some shared file), however they have different permissions since one is under application folder and another is under download folder.

Comment: I had similar situation on macOS. I had 2 VS Code versions installed. One in Applications, other in Desktop folder. Exiting VS Code, deleting one and using the remaining one, solved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

This answer applies if using VSCode in GitHub Codespaces in Firefox or Brave browsers. I had to disable "Enhanced Tracking Protection" for the site, and that is all. To do so, click on the shield icon which is to the left of the displayed web address.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is using Brave, please turn off the brave shields as well.

Comment: at least changing browser from Brave helps to avoid this error, thanks

Comment: Had this problem when browsing code on Github in "VS Code" mode using Brave, that helped.

Answer (score 2):

Try closing all the process `cmd+q`of vscode and reopen vscode and everything should work well.

Answer (score 2):

There is another possible reason for OSX, that the files in the following paths are restricted by user permissions.

MAC: `/Users/<userid>/Library/Application Support`

As shown below
[image]

[image]

You can directly delete folders with restricted permissions.

After restarting VScode, he will generate it again.

Answer (score 1):

For Mac/Apple computer Monteray version the following steps worked for me:

1. Delete VSCode from downloads folder.
2. Turn off VSCode
3. Open Activity Monitor and delete VSCode "Code" process.

[image: VSCODE CODE PROCESS]

Answer (score 1):

I have just restarted VS code and it worked for me. OS was Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

For me (OSX) the answer was to delete cache, but on a different path:

```bash
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Code/Cache
```

Comment: Thanks! I helped me to solve the issue to be failed to load the webview in vscode.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on `Ubuntu 22.04` and it appears that this come from the `~/.config/Code` folder. Simply deleting it fixed the issue for me, however I'll have to reinstall all my extensions...

Thanks [@hgehlhausen](https://github.com/hgehlhausen) on https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/125993

Comment: [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69313758/11107541) already links to that issue ticket and talks about deleting the cache folder. why delete the whole config folder though?

Comment: I’ve tried to simply delete the cache folder and it didn’t fix the issue in my case.

Answer (score 0):

For me, reloading VSCode wasn't enough. I reloaded my computer and everything worked.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem when trying to rebase after a VSCode update. I had to do the following :

- Check code availability: run `code --version` in console.
- Set Visual Studio Code as Git's default editor behaviour to "wait" :
  `git config --global core.editor "code --wait"`

The `--wait` flag with code makes Visual Studio Code stay open until you close the file. It's useful with Git, so the command line waits until you're done editing the file related to your Git operation.