# When I update my VSCode to v1.56.2, I can't run Jupyter Notebook

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I update my VSCode to v1.56.2, I can't run Jupyter Notebook.

VScode doesn't show any code by .ipynb format but .py format is okay and I can see this Error:

> Error loading webview: Error: Could not register service workers: InvalidStateError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The document is in an invalid state..

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: possibly related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/137341 -> https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/125993

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows, you can simply fix this error by clearing the cache for VSCode. Please follow the steps below:

1. Close VSCode and also kill any background processes running in the task manager.
2. Go to the file explorer and to the path `C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Roaming\Code` and clear the contents of the folders `Cache, CachedData, CachedExtensions, CachedExtensionVSIXs (if this folder exists) and Code Cache.`
3. Open VSCode and you are good to go

also, you can see this issue:

[Error loading webview: Error: Could not register service workers: TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67698176/error-loading-webview-error-could-not-register-service-workers-typeerror-fai)