# Images not loading in my VS Code project folder. It says failed to register a service worker

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, mobile, pubspec.yaml

The images in my project are not loading. I keep getting this error anytime I try to view it. I can't run my projects:

Error loading webview: Error: Could not register service workers: InvalidStateError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The document is in an invalid state..

[image: This is the error I got]

Comment: can you show me the pubspec.yaml file

Comment: if your C drive is full you get this error

Comment: @ZeyadMohamed he wants to preview an image in VSC, it has nothing to do with `pubspec.yaml`

Comment: possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67698176/11107541

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can not put assets folder inside lib,
lib folder is only for .dart files[image: use this]