# Error while opening ipynb notebook in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I was just writing a python code and after switching folder, it threw an error stating:-

Error loading webview: Error: Could not register service workers: InvalidStateError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The document is in an invalid state.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67698176/error-loading-webview-error-could-not-register-service-workers-typeerror-fai) which can help.

Emptying the cache is an effective solution.

The simplest step is `killall code` or restart vscode.

Comment: this is when you should close-vote